# Calculating elapsed “times” in R, where the time depends on a factor

Tags: r, time, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 150,000 + rows but here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
 TIME_REAL   HR Behaviour
 21:15:00   54  Eupnoea
 21:15:01   107 Eupnoea
 21:15:02   118 Eupnoea
 21:15:03   75  Eupnoea
 21:15:04   94  Eupnoea
 21:15:05   57  Eupnoea
 21:15:06   106 Eupnoea
 21:15:07   121 Eupnoea
 21:15:08   104 Eupnoea
 21:15:09   73  Eupnoea
 21:15:10   114 Apnoea
 21:15:11   108 Apnoea
 21:15:12   121 Apnoea
 21:15:13   117 Apnoea
 21:15:14   110 Apnoea
 21:15:15   38  Eupnoea
 21:15:16   120 Eupnoea
 21:15:17   118 Eupnoea
 21:15:18   82  Eupnoea
 21:15:19   107 Eupnoea
 21:15:20   44  Apnoea
```

I am trying to calculate the duration of the behavioural event (factor) - so the first eupnoea event would be 9 seconds long, followed by an apnoea event of 4 second etc. Ideally I would like a separate table or columns with each time the event happens and the duration of the behavioural event. I have tried to use the dplyr package but have not had any success. I would also like to calculate the average HR for each time the behaviour event happens... is there anyway to do this in R??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include an example of what the output should look like?  You can also include the code of the attempt you made that failed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
dff$TIME_REAL <- as.POSIXct(strptime(dff$TIME_REAL, '%H:%M:%S'))

make_splitter <- function(col_vals) {
  rle_lengths <- rle(as.character(col_vals))$lengths
  rep(1:length(rle_lengths), rle_lengths)
}

dff %>%
group_by(splitter = make_splitter(Behaviour), Behaviour) %>%
summarise(Average_HR = mean(HR),
        Start_Time = strftime(head(TIME_REAL, 1), '%H:%M:%S'),
        End_Time = strftime(tail(TIME_REAL, 1), '%H:%M:%S'),
        Duration = difftime(tail(TIME_REAL, 1), head(TIME_REAL, 1)))
```

First, create a function that helps define how you want to split the dataframe. Here, I use the `rle` function and some replicating to get the ideal column.

Assuming that your current dataframe is called `dff`, you can coerce the `TIME_REAL` column to `as.POSIXct` objects before you can go ahead and do any calculation on it. Subsequently, you can use `dplyr` to group by both the splitter column and the `Behavior` column, and then use the `summarise` function to get the average average `HR` and the time differences.

Should yield:

```
  Behaviour Average_HR Start_Time End_Time Duration
     <fctr>      <dbl>      <chr>    <chr>   <time>
1   Eupnoea       90.9   21:15:00 21:15:09   9 secs
2    Apnoea      114.0   21:15:10 21:15:14   4 secs
3   Eupnoea       93.0   21:15:15 21:15:19   4 secs
4    Apnoea       44.0   21:15:20 21:15:20   0 secs
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I cannot get it to work as the behaviours are factors.... with the error message "max not meaningful for factors". I can't transform them into anything else - do you know a way around this?

Comment: @dphil, where is the error coming from? The code here works fine when the `Behavior` column is a `factor`. Either way, you should be able to use `as.character` temporarily on any `factor` value.

Comment: I have no idea why it wouldn't work but thank you so much, after playing around with it, it works perfectly. Is there any way in which the start time and end time might be added to this output (sorry!!) The duration is great but there may also be a diurnal effect present which I realise will be difficult to tell from this.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tribble(
  ~TIME_REAL,   ~HR, ~Behaviour,
  "21:15:00",   54,  "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:01",   107, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:02",   118, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:03",   75,  "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:04",   94,  "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:05",   57,  "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:06",   106, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:07",   121, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:08",   104, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:09",   73,  "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:10",   114, "Apnoea",
  "21:15:11",   108, "Apnoea",
  "21:15:12",   121, "Apnoea",
  "21:15:13",   117, "Apnoea",
  "21:15:14",   110, "Apnoea",
  "21:15:15",   38,  "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:16",   120, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:17",   118, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:18",   82,  "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:19",   107, "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:20",   44,  "Apnoea"
)

myle <- rle(tbl$Behaviour)
tbl %>% 
  mutate(code = rep(seq_along(myle$values), myle$lengths)) %>%
  group_by(Behaviour, code) %>%
  summarise(N = n(), mean = mean(HR)) %>% 
  arrange(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to that with `dplyr`, with the help of `rleid` from `data.table`. I use `rleid`, because it's an easy way to add a group number. I'm also using `as.POSIXct` to transform the time column to a time object, which is easier to do operations on.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(TIME_REAL=as.POSIXct(TIME_REAL,format="%H:%M:%S"),
           behaviour_number=data.table::rleid(Behaviour))%>%
  group_by(behaviour_number)%>%
  summarise(behaviour=max(Behaviour),elapsed=max(TIME_REAL)-min(TIME_REAL),
            HR_avg=mean(HR,na.rm=TRUE))

  behaviour_number behaviour elapsed HR_avg
             <int>     <chr>  <time>  <dbl>
1                1   Eupnoea  9 secs   90.9
2                2    Apnoea  4 secs  114.0
3                3   Eupnoea  4 secs   93.0
4                4    Apnoea  0 secs   44.0
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="TIME_REAL   HR Behaviour
 21:15:00   54  Eupnoea
                 21:15:01   107 Eupnoea
                 21:15:02   118 Eupnoea
                 21:15:03   75  Eupnoea
                 21:15:04   94  Eupnoea
                 21:15:05   57  Eupnoea
                 21:15:06   106 Eupnoea
                 21:15:07   121 Eupnoea
                 21:15:08   104 Eupnoea
                 21:15:09   73  Eupnoea
                 21:15:10   114 Apnoea
                 21:15:11   108 Apnoea
                 21:15:12   121 Apnoea
                 21:15:13   117 Apnoea
                 21:15:14   110 Apnoea
                 21:15:15   38  Eupnoea
                 21:15:16   120 Eupnoea
                 21:15:17   118 Eupnoea
                 21:15:18   82  Eupnoea
                 21:15:19   107 Eupnoea
                 21:15:20   44  Apnoea",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with date, I recommend to go for `lubridate`.

Here you need to construct a complete date format in order to work with date. For the sake of this example, let's assume the day is today.

```
library(tidyverse)
try <- tribble(
  ~TIME_REAL, ~Behaviour,
  "21:15:00", "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:03", "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:04", "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:09", "Eupnoea",
  "21:15:10", "Apnoea",
  "21:15:15", "Apnoea",
  "21:15:17", "Apnoea",
  "21:15:18", "Apnoea"
)
library(lubridate)
try %>%
  mutate(TIME_REAL = paste(today(), TIME_REAL)) %>%
  mutate(TIME_REAL = ymd_hms(TIME_REAL)) %>%
  group_by(Behaviour) %>%
  summarize(time = max(TIME_REAL) - min(TIME_REAL))


# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Behaviour   time
      <chr> <time>
1    Apnoea 8 secs
2   Eupnoea 9 secs
```

Here the two `mutate` calls transform the date to an ISO8601. You can then group_by and do basic maths.

Hope this can help

Colin